# I create a leave app but there is issue when i sending notification from one activity to second and second to third using TOPIC in FirebaseNotifiServ

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, notificationservices

I use IF condition in firebase Notification services class but this condition did not work then i create two diff TOPIC, they also did not work what can i do.....the condition i create it in firebase notification services class is:

```
public class FirebaseNoficationservices extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private final String CHANNEL_ID="channel_id";
   // private  final String CHANNEL_IDD="channel_idd";
    //String topic;
   Intent intent;

    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("remote", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        if((FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("ahmedraza"))!=null){
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DepartmentHead.class);
        }
        else if((FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("ahmedraza"))!=null){
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admin.class);
        }

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            int notificationId = new Random().nextInt();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                createNotificationChannel(manager);
            }

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("key", remoteMessage.getData().get("name"));

            PendingIntent intent1 = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0, new Intent[]{intent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            Notification notification;
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.name)))
                    .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.department)))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.rx_notification)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(intent1)
                    .build();
            manager.notify(notificationId, notification);
        }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager manager) {
        NotificationChannel channel=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"channelName",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("My description");
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLightColor(android.R.color.white);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

and my main application code are:

```
  if(sendtoDepthead.isChecked()) {
                      PushNotification notification = new PushNotification(new notificationData(fulnamee.getText().toString(), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()), TOPIC);
                      sendNotification(notification);
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "notification sent to manager", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                  if(sendtoGeneralmanager.isChecked()){
                      PushNotification notification = new PushNotification(new notificationData(fulnamee.getText().toString(), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()), TOPICS);
                      sendNotification(notification);
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "notification sent to manager", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

and topic subscribe in department head activity is:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(TOPIC);

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(TOPIC)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        String msg = "Subscribed";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            msg = "Subscribe failed";
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, msg);
                        Toast.makeText(DepartmentHead.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

and the code of notification i send to department head to admin activity is:

```
 PushNotification notification=new PushNotification(new notificationData(nam.getText().toString(),dept.getText().toString()),TOPICS);
                sendNotification(notification);
                Toast.makeText(DepartmentHead.this,"notification sent to manager",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and topic subscribe in my admin activity are:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(TOPICS)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        String msg = "Subscribed";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            msg = "Subscribe failed";
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, msg);
                        `Toast.makeText(Admin.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
                    }
                });
```

What can i do to get the notification...in application no crashes occur only notification were not send to admin or dept. head classes.

After send the notification i will also send data( using data key) with notification...but i can send notification.
**can anyone help me to correct the condition of sending to notification for one class to second and second to third.**

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: app cant be crash..problem is i cant get a notification

Comment: i don't know how to create a condition to get the notification form two different classes

Comment: @AlexMamo app cant be crash its open when i send notification notification not working.